# Can't update react-dom 15.6.1 to 16.x.x

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-2017, react-dom

I want to update my react app that I created with VS2017 to react 16 so I can use fragments. Updating the 'react' package works fine but I'm struggling with 'react-dom'.

Steps to reproduce (what I've done):

1. Open VS2017
2. Create new 'ASP.NET Core Web Application'
3. Select 'React.js and Redux'
4. Edit package.json like this:

> ```
> "devDependencies": { 
>     "@types/react": "^16.3.14", 
>     "@types/react-dom": "^16.0.5",
>     "react": "^16.3.2",
>     "react-dom": "^16.3.2"
>  }
> ```

5. Edit a file in ClientApp (eg. ClientApp/boot-client.tsx)

> ```
> import * as React from 'react';
> import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
> console.log(React.version);
> console.log(ReactDOM.version);
> ```

6. Update npm packages (Right click on package.json -> Restore or 'npm install' in project directory)

Excpected output from those two console.log lines:

```
16.3.2
16.3.2
```

Actual output:

```
16.3.2
15.6.1
```

Now that the 'react-dom' version isn't 16.x.x I can't use fragments.
I checked following files and all versions seem to be correct (16.x.x)

```
npm_modules/@types/react/package.json
npm_modules/@types/react-dom/package.json
npm_modules/react/package.json
npm_modules/react-dom/package.json
```

I can't figure out, what I'm doing wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried deleting `node_modules` before restoring? Sometimes that clears up these kinds of issues. Also, make sure you don't have packages listed twice in your `package.json` - seeing React listed under `devDependencies` makes me wonder if you still have an old version listed under `dependencies`.

Comment: As Joe Clay says, I don't think you should have React in devDependencies...

Comment: Try deleting `package-lock.json` and re-running `npm install`. Earlier versions of NPM used `package-lock.json` as the source of truth instead of `package.json`. If deleting the package lock and re-generating it works for you, also update NPM to the latest production version.

Comment: @JoeClay I tried deleting `node_modules`. The project created by VS2017 doesn't have any `dependencies` only `devDependencies`. Moving those four definitions to `dependencies` didn't help.

Comment: @RossAllen I also tried your suggestion but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command in the command prompt after changing the directory by using cd to the client app folder of your project.

```
npm install --save react@^16.8.0 react-dom@^16.8.0
```

With the above command, you can update react and react-dom to the desired versions.